# How to subscribe to two or more Svelte stores?

Tags: svelte

Given the case that I have two stores and a function, that should run every time one of the stores changes

```js
export const s1 = writable('store1')
export const s2 = writable('store2')

export function onStoreChange(triggeredFrom) {
    console.log('a store has changed! - ', triggeredFrom)
}
```

Ways I know to handle this 'double subscription' would be inside a .svelte file

```js
$: $s1, $s2, onStoreChange('component')
```

and inside a javascript file with subscribing to the two stores seperately

```js
const unsubS1 = s1.subscribe(v => {
    onStoreChange('s1 subscription')
})

const unsubS2 = s2.subscribe(v => {
    onStoreChange('s2 subscription')
})
```

but I'm wondering if there's a more concise way to this, combining the two (or more) subscriptions inside a .js file?

I thought about (mis)using a derived store

```js
export const derivedStore = derived(
        [s1, s2],
            ([$s1, $s2]) => {                 
                    onStoreChange('derived Store', $s1, $s2)
            }
)
```

but in this case the store value isn't used anywhere and because of that it looks like the derived store doesn't 'survive' compiling - even if the value must have changed, the function inside doesn't run. Thanks to @voscausa for pointing out, that *"a store will only run if it has a subscriber"* - so the functionality of a derived store doesn't match directly to what I'm looking for but could be complemented with a subscription like this

```js
export const derivedStore = derived(
        [s1, s2],
            ([$s1, $s2]) => [$s1, $s2]
)

const unsubDerivedStore = derivedStore.subscribe(value => {
   onStoreChange('derived Store', ...value)
)
```

Is this the best way for such a 'multi subscription' or is there an alternative?

a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/2af97bb9d85b4f96bd4d3173631147eb?version=3.44.1)

(Background behind the question is not only to maybe write less code, but to have both values 'directly available' without using `get()`)

```js
$: $s1, $s2, onStoreChange($s1, $s2)

// vs

const unsubS1 = s1.subscribe(s1 => {
    onStoreChange(s1, get(s2))
})

const unsubS2 = s2.subscribe(s2Value => {
    onStoreChange(get(s1), s2)
})
```

Answer (score 4):

This is where you can use a derived store like

```
const s3 = derived([s1, s2], ([$s1, $s2]) => [$s1, $s2]);
```

Store s3 returns an array with the store latest store values from both if one of these stores changes.

And you can create a derived store in a js file. The $ prefix here is  to make clear it's the store value and not the store.

So this will work as well:

```
const s3 = derived([s1, s2], ([v1, v2]) => [v1, v2]);
```

Comment: Thanks voscausa! But this doesn't seem to solve the problem unfortunately. In the scenario I don't want to use the derived value somewhere, but only run a function when one store changes. And if the value of the derived store isn't used somewhere, it looks like the compiler decides that it's unnecessary and it gets excluded. Returning both values doesn't seem to change that.

Comment: Have a look at the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/2af97bb9d85b4f96bd4d3173631147eb?version=3.44.1) In App.svelte line 6 there's a log of the derived store value. If that's active, the function inside the derivedStore gets executed. If the log is not active and the derivedStore isn't used at all, it's not. Maybe there's a way to say that the store is important, even though it's return value is not used? (like with css :global())

Answer (score 1):

If you want to subscribe to multiple stores without using `derived` and want to use it in a JS file you can use something like this :

```
function subscribeMultiples(stores, callback)
{
    // Store values of all the stores
    const values = [];
    const unsubscribes = [];
    // Subscribe to all the stores
    for (let i = 0; i < stores.length; i++)
    {
        unsubscribes[i] = stores[i].subscribe((value) => {
            values[i] = value;
            // Call the callback when all the stores have values
            if (values.length == stores.length) callback(values);
        });
    }

    return () => {
        unsubscribes.forEach((unsubscribe) => unsubscribe());
    }
}
```

Which you can use like so :

```
subscribeMultiples([s1, s2], ([$s1, $s2]) => {
    console.log("subscribeMultiples", $s1, $s2);
});
```

It's a simplified version of how `derived` works.

Answer (score 0):

I tested my code and it works fine.

s3 has to comeup with a **new value** every time s1 or s2 changes!
A store will do nothing if it's returned value does not change.

The array returned by s3 makes sure s3 will change every time s1 or s2 changes.
But there is no need to use the array result in App.svelte. It's not used.

So here is my App.svelte:

```
<script>
    import {s1, s2, s3} from "./stores.js";
    let i = 0;

    function fn() {
        console.log("s3 triggered fn"); 
    }

    $: if ($s3) fn(); 
</script>

<h1>Test derived</h1>

<button on:click={() => {
 i += 1;
 $s1 = i;
}}>
    button-s1
</button>

<button on:click={() => {
 i += 1;
 $s2 = i;
}}>
     button-s2
</button>
```

And the stores.js

```
import {writable, derived} from "svelte/store"

export const s1 = writable(0);
export const s2 = writable(0);
export const s3 = derived([s1, s2], ([$s1, $s2]) => {
    console.log("derived", $s1, $s2);
    return [$s1, $s2];
});
```

Comment: Thanks again! Your code is working, because you track the value of s3 inside App.svelte. If you uncomment the line ` $: if ($s3) fn();` and change s1 or s2 via the buttons it could be assumed that s3 still changes and the log inside the derived store will run? But that's not the case! A [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/8d8e146e1fe446808f19ed417f297de5?version=3.44.1) with your code to try

Comment: A store will only run if it has a subscriber.  If you comment out the $: if($s3) .. there is no subscriber.

Comment: Ah I see, then the behaviour makes sense, thanks for pointing out! But then the derived store won't be a solution for the original question (a way to subscribe to two stores 'simultaniously' and run function if one changes - **inside .js file**) Inside a .svelte file the reactivity could easily be achieved by `$: $s1, $s2, onStoreChange('component')` even without the derived store

Comment: I give up. inside a js file you can subribe to s3. You do not need the $store syntax to subscribe.

Comment: I don't want to subscribe to s3..... I'm looking for a way to subscribe to s1 and s2 'in one go'. Of course there's the possibility to create the derived s3 and then on top subsribe to that again. But that's a bit 'around the corner' and I don't see much gain to the parallel s1/s2 subscripton (I mentioned in the question)

Comment: Ok, after writing it down I think it's an improvement. So thanks again for time and patience! :)